# Pugixml: No document element found

Tags: c++, xml, pugixml

I'm having some trouble loading the document (see link http://pastebin.com/FE3nDX9h) in pugixml.
I'm getting an error code of `16`: `No document element found` which indicates that the XML file is invalid or empty which I think is neither.
I am using the default parsing method. Is there something I am missing?

edit: as requested heres some source code http://pastebin.com/USUjLC4q you will need to edit the paths.

Comment: how do you do this? could you show your code?

Comment: added some source code, although I don't believe that's the problem.

Comment: I tried changing the XML attributes guid and path to nodes (children of video) to test any limitations on XML attributes but that returned the same error code 16.

Answer (score 7):

You need `xml_document::load_file` but `xml_document::load`.

[From pugi documentation](http://pugixml.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/docs/quickstart.html):

> There is also a simple helper function, xml_document::load, for cases when you want to load the XML document from null-terminated character string.

So, `load`'s argument has to be xml by itself, not file name.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick annoying how the little things just slip the mind. To anyone else reading this give johny an upvote!

Comment: "No document element found" error was added exactly because of load vs load_file confusion, so it works... In retrospect load should have been called load_string, but it's impossible to change at this moment :(